# How Phusion Passenger with Nginx process requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm a Rails developer with some experience (1.5 years), but I still doesn't know how Phusion Passenger processes requests. I understand that at first Nginx catch request and passes my request to Phusion Passenger, but what happens later? 
How memory does Passenger use? Is there a thread/process for each request or not? There is only one copy of Passenger in memory or not? Please, explain me the algorithm. Also, how many cores of my system can Passenger use? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Passenger author here. Most of your questions are explained in Passenger's [Design and Architecture](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Design%20and%20Architecture.html) document. There is also a lot of information in the [Raptor blog posts](http://www.rubyraptor.org/how-we-made-raptor-up-to-4x-faster-than-unicorn-and-up-to-2x-faster-than-puma-torquebox/).

Some specific answers to questions not answered in that document:

- "How memory does Passenger use?" -- Passenger *itself* (not counting the application) uses about 4 MB in total.
- "Also, how many cores of my system can Passenger use?" -- It can use all your cores. Whether the *application* can use all your cores is a different question, and has got nothing to do with how many Passenger can use.